# Installing just autoware_msgs from autoware.ai, possible?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

Is it possible to install only autoware_msgs from the messages directory in [autoware.ai repo](https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/messages). The pc uses CUDA 10.2 which goes against the dependencies and also I don't need all other messages.

I tried to cherry pick the msgs inside autoware_msgs and put it as custom messages to my `ros2_ws/src` directory. I have the Package.xml and CMakeLists.txt linked. I also converted them to reflect ROS2 standards. After building it and locally ros sourcing the project I was able access the msg in `ros2 msg list`

```
$ ros2 msg list | grep "lane_"
lane_following_msgs/msg/AccelCmd
lane_following_msgs/msg/BrakeCmd
lane_following_msgs/msg/ControlCommand
lane_following_msgs/msg/ControlCommandStamped
lane_following_msgs/msg/Gear
lane_following_msgs/msg/IndicatorCmd
lane_following_msgs/msg/LampCmd
lane_following_msgs/msg/SteerCmd
lane_following_msgs/msg/VehicleCmd
lane_following_msgs/msg/VehicleLocation

$ ros2 msg show lane_following_msgs/msg/VehicleCmd 
std_msgs/Header header
lane_following_msgs/SteerCmd steer_cmd
lane_following_msgs/AccelCmd accel_cmd
lane_following_msgs/BrakeCmd brake_cmd
lane_following_msgs/LampCmd lamp_cmd
lane_following_msgs/Gear gear_cmd
int32 mode
geometry_msgs/TwistStamped twist_cmd
lane_following_msgs/ControlCommand ctrl_cmd
int32 emergency

$ ros2 topic list
/parameter_events
/rosout
/simulator/camera_node/left/image/compressed
/simulator/camera_node/main/image/compressed
/simulator/camera_node/right/image/compressed
/vehicleCmd
```

However when I tried to use the *VehicleCmd.msg* with LGSVL Autoware, ros2-web-bridge, `/vehicle_cmd` with message type `autoware_msgs/VehicleCmd`, I wasn't able to send any data. What was I doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated? Thanks.

**Setup -**

Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, Kernel: 5.3.0-46-generic x86_64, ros-dashing-desktop. CUDA 10.2

$ env |grep ROS

```
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/melodic/etc/ros
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/melodic/share/ros
ROS_VERSION=2
ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=3
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/melodic/share
ROS_DISTRO=dashing
```

**Pastebin links**
Package.XML-- https://pastebin.com/G9hdZ6AA
CMakeLists.txt  -- https://pastebin.com/WbMgEfH5

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351164/installing-just-autoware_msgs-from-autoware.ai,-possible?/) by [dr563105](https://answers.ros.org/users/53917/dr563105/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2020-05-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `messages` repository has been released into the ROS build farm so you can install `autoware_msgs` as the package `ros-melodic-autoware-msgs`.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2020-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dr563105](https://answers.ros.org/users/53917/dr563105/) on 2020-05-01**:
Thank you. I was able to install.
Then to export the library to VS code, I export this path -- `/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`?

Since the new distro Noetic is not out yet, will import this msg library, compel me to use python2.7 and ROS1?

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2020-05-03**:
Noetic is still ROS 1 - it will likely be the last release of ROS 1. Melodic does not require Python3 but most packages comply with it. However, 2.7 is the supported version for Melodic.

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2020-05-03**:
BTW, nothing in Autoware.ai is compatible with ROS2. Autoware.Auto is built on ROS2.